# Reading content of a URL in Grails/Groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Is there are easy way of parsing the whole HTML page and extract a specific section from the code of that page? i.e. i got this URL from the RSS feed of this [site](http://www.groundreport.com/): http://www.groundreport.com/Sports/Bret-Hart-says-Farewell-to-WWE_4/2918823

What i want to do is parse that link and retrieve related images, tags, and other info from that page. Is there a Java library or Grails plugin that can easily parse an HTML code?

Your suggestion on how to approach this task will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Tagsoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) library.
There is an example [here](http://blog.foosion.org/2008/06/09/parse-html-the-groovy-way/).

Answer (score 0):

I briefly looked at [WebHarvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/index.php) over a year ago and it seemed nice.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is well-formed XML, you can use any Groovy XML parsing technique. In practice, you probably won't be able to guarantee this, so a HTML parser is a better option. In the past, I've used the [Jericho HTML parser](http://jerichohtml.sourceforge.net/) (a Java library) and have been very satisfied with the results.